# Lebesgue–Radon–Nikodym Theorem Explanation

Tags: measure-theory, derivatives

From Folland, the theorem is as follows:

> **The Lebsgue–Radon–Nikodym Theorem**  Let $\nu$ be a $\sigma$-finite signed measure and $\mu$ a $\sigma$-finite positive measure on $(X,\mathcal{M})$. There exists unique $\sigma$-finite signed measure $\lambda,\rho$ on $(X,\mathcal{M})$ such that $\lambda\perp \mu$, $\rho\ll\mu$, and $\nu=\lambda+\rho$. Moreover, there is an extended $\mu$-integrable function $f: X\to\mathbb{R}$ such that $d\rho=f\,d\mu$, and any two functions are equal $\mu$-a.e.

The statement of the theorem itself seems straightforward. However, I am confused as to the later claim in Folland:

> In the case where $\nu\ll\mu$, the theorem says that $d\nu = f \, d\nu$ for some $f$

I would really appreciate a simple and intuitive explanation of this.

Comment: Attempt at solution: If $ν≪μ$, then letting $\lambda = 0$ we see that $\lambda \perp \mu$, so by uniqueness the decomposition is simply $\nu = 0 +\nu$.  Thus the result follows.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The LRN theorem lets us decompose one measure with respect to another -- one part singular and one part absolutely continuous. If $\nu \ll \mu$, then there can be no singular part.

This is because $\nu \ll \mu$ says that if $\mu(E) = 0$, then $\nu(E) = 0$ too. But if $\nu = \lambda + \rho$ with $\lambda \perp \mu$, then $X = E \sqcup F$ where $F$ is $\mu$-null and $E$ is $\lambda$-null, but then $F$ is $\mu$-null, $F$ must also be $\nu$-null because in this case, $\nu \ll \mu$, so $F$ must also be $\lambda$-null. But then $X$ is $\lambda$-null, so that $\lambda \equiv 0$.

Comment: It's worth mentioning $\rho\ll \mu$ implies that $F$ is $\rho$-null - hence $F$ is $\lambda$-null.